# Checkout in a mobile screen

Tags: mobile

Is it better to have a single checkout screen where the user is asked to enter pickup address, delivery address and time? Or should the two addresses (pick up and delivery) be kept together on a single screen and the next screen asks the time?

Which option is better in terms of a better UX flow:
1. Choose addresses : pick up and delivery ---> Choose time
2. Choose everything in one screen

Comment: It should be either a pick up or a delivery, right? Why both?

Comment: This is for a logistics space. I want to send something from one place to another. Hence, both.

Comment: Oh ok. Got it. This is available both on touch and non - touch interface?

Comment: This is for a typical android app. Touch.

Answer (score 1):

I would say use one screen per address entry at a time. I've found it's easier to use an app if we present the screens as per the process flow in the mind of user and one thing at a time works better on mobile screens in such cases (I work in a logistics company).

Also, I understand there will be time selection for both pick-up and delivery which you can club with their respective addresses on a single screen so, two high-level screens would be needed.

Comment: It is the pick up time.
Does it make sense to have a master screen for both addresses (pickup and delivery). User clicks on the addresses one by one to go into another screen where he can actually enter addresses or choose from existing ones.
Once both the addresses are entered, the user moves on to entering the pick up time. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make the assumption that you need the time mentioned for pickup and delivery. 
I would go with placing the pickup address screen along with the time of pickup in one screen and the next screen would be the delivery address (with the option of delivery time?). 
Think of this logically, without pickup there would be no delivery, hence it is important to map this flow which the user is most comfortable with. Also I would not split the time into a new screen since that would need me to recall the address information from an earlier screen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is just the pick-up time.
Won't it make more sense to take both addresses in a single screen? Because logically, user would think about the source and destination first? And then later, the pick up time.

Comment: You will need to carry out user research to actually come to a conclusion that fits your use case. Sample a few users likely to use the application and see what they feel is comfortable. Logically grouping pickup time and pickup address makes sense to me.